# can somebody explain this C error message?

Tags: c, xcode, switch-statement

I'm writing a program to take two numbers and an operator and perform a calculation. I've written it in Objective-C previously, and am going back over my work and trying to write it in C with switch statements. I keep getting the following error message:
"Passing 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'cont char *'" in relation to the line where I call and print my function (right before the `return 0;` at the end). I'd like to understand what is actually causing this issue (vs just finding out how to fix it). I want to make sure I can avoid this from happening down the line, whatever the reason.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    double calculator(double x,char y, double z) {
        switch (y) {
            case '+':
                return x+z;
                break;
             case '-':
                return x-z;
                break;
            case '/':
                return x/z;
                break;
            case '*':
                return x*z;
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
                break;
                }
    }


    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        char y;
        double x, z;

        printf ("Please enter a number to be operated on\n");
        scanf("%lf", &x);
        printf ("Enter a valid operator\n");
        scanf("%s", &y);
        printf("Please enter a second number to complete the calculation\n");
        scanf("%lf", &x);

        printf (calculator(x,y,z));

                return 0;

    }
```

Comment: There is nothing to explain, the message is clear.

Comment: I'm an idiot...I set the third scan item (the second number to complete the calculation) to be x, overwriting the previous declaration. WHOOPS.

Comment: `printf ("%f", calculator(x,y,z));`

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of `printf()` is

```
printf(const char*,...);
```

but you are passing `double` to it hence the error

Comment: so then I just need to specify that I'll be passing a double (or a float) with "%f", correct? Worked when I ran it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has several problems, each line of it is likely to be wrong

1. You pass a `char` to `scanf()` with the `"%s"` specifier, `scanf()` will think it's a `char` pointer and it will try to store at least 2 characters in it, but there is only space for one. The correct specifier is `"%c"`, you should leave a white space in front of the `c` or it will consume the `'\n'` left in the buffer by the previous `scanf()`.
2. You don't check for the return value of `scanf()` which will cause undefined behavior when you call `calculator()`.
3. You passed a `double` as the first parameter to `printf()`, it expects a `char` pointer, and preferrably pointing to a string literal, to print a `double` you need

   ```
   printf("%f", doubleValue);
   ```

This code would fix all what I point above

```
#include <stdio.h>

double calculator(double x, char operator double y)
{
    switch (operator)
    {
    case '+':
        return x + y;
     case '-':
        return x - y;
    case '/':
        if (y == 0)
            return 0.0; /* division by zero */
        return x / y;
    case '*':
        return x * y;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0.0;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char   operator;
    double x, y;

    printf("Please enter a number to be operated on\n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        return -1;
     }

    printf ("Enter a valid operator\n");
    if (scanf(" %c", &operator) != 1)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        return -1;
     }

    printf("Please enter a second number to complete the calculation\n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &y) != 1)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        return -1;
     }
    printf("%f %c %f = %f\n", x, operator, y, calculator(x, operator, y));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does "stderr" do? Also, when you get the if statements in the code body not equal to "1", are you saying that somebody didn't enter a value for the variable? As in, 1 is true, it is true that we scanned for an input and didn't receive one?

Comment: @karansatia No, it's the number of format specifiers that matched the input, in this case it's just one, before you use any function, read the documentation until you fully understand what the function does and how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype of printf function is:

`int printf( const char *format ,…)`

format - It is constant character string.

```
 double calculator(double x,char y, double z) {
```

but the function is returning double value.
so it is printing error message as

> "Passing 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'cont char *'"